# "Current location" text should be change according to the language in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In my app When I click on my current location, it shows "Current Location" and when I change the language to german it shows "Aktueller Ort" in the iOS version < 6.0. But in iOS >=6.0, it always shows "Current Location". Is this an issue of Apple Maps?

Comment: Where do you mean.I have selected turkish on my Iphone and it is shown in turkish on the top of the list

Comment: In default maps it is showing in different language. But in mkmapview which i took in my app it is not showing..It is still showing "Current Location".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the problem.. We have to make "Localized resources can be mixed" tag True in info.plist file. Now it will work in all languages.. (Y)